# Normal Map has seams when applied in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I baked it with bake type normal, space tangent in blender cycles. The map itself seems to look fine, but when applied to the normal slot it looks broken at the seams.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the image texture to Non-Color-Data.

Now it works.